# How to remove custom background?

Tags: custom-background

I'm using WordPress 3.5.1 and twentyten.

I want to remove the support for custom background. I found this text: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_custom_background

but i'm a newbie in php, so I dont know what to do whit the information.

I guess I should use this code `<?php remove_custom_background() ?>` 
but what to do with it? where should I put it?

Thanks!
/Frida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the theme folder there should be a file called `functions.php`. Search for the line

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );
```

and replace it with

```
#add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );
```

which is simply 'deleting' calling the function and thus the possibility to specify a custom background in the admin side.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. One note, however: every time you update the theme (which does not happen that often, and it is your choice to do so), the file `functions.php` (as well as every other theme file) will be overwritten, and so your edit. So just redo what you did to the line after an update and you'll be fine.